# How to pipe uncompressed video from FFMPEG subprocess to python?

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg, pipe

I got a problem with my program. It has no output. I try to make a Webcamvideostream on my raspberry pi 4 and try to use ffmpeg to handle the frame grabbing in python. My Problem is, that the output looks terrible. No real picture from my cam. Is it the wrong pixel format? I show you the code:

```
    import os
    import tempfile
    import subprocess
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    
    # To get this path execute:
    #    $ which ffmpeg
    FFMPEG_BIN = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg'
    width = 1280
    height = 720
    def run_ffmpeg():
        ffmpg_cmd = [
            FFMPEG_BIN,
            '-f', 'video4linux2',
            '-framerate', '30',
            '-input_format', 'mjpeg',
            '-video_size', f'{width}x{height}',
            '-i', '/dev/video0',
            '-filter:v', 'crop=1280:720:0:0',
            #'-an','-sn',                # disable audio processing
            '-f', 'image2pipe',
            '-',                        # output to go to stdout
        ]
        return subprocess.Popen(ffmpg_cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)
    
    def run_cv_window(process):
        while True:
            # read frame-by-frame
            raw_image = process.stdout.read(width*height*3)
            if raw_image == b'':
                raise RuntimeError("Empty pipe")
            
            # transform the bytes read into a numpy array
            frame =  np.frombuffer(raw_image, dtype='uint8')
            frame = frame.reshape((height,width,3)) # height, width, channels
            if frame is not None:
                cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
            
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
            process.stdout.flush()
        
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        process.terminate()
        print(process.poll())
    
    def run():
        ffmpeg_process = run_ffmpeg()
        run_cv_window(ffmpeg_process)
    
    run()
```

This is the following output on the console:

```
        libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
      libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
      libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
      libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
      libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
      libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
      libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
      libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
      libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
    Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
      Duration: N/A, start: 16744.936817, bitrate: N/A
        Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> mjpeg (native))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    Output #0, image2pipe, to 'pipe:':
      Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
        Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc), 1280x720, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 mjpeg
        Side data:
          cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    frame=   13 fps=0.0 q=24.8 size=     557kB time=00:00:00.43 bitrate=10531.4kbits/s speed=0.846x    
    frame=   29 fps= 28 q=24.8 size=     983kB time=00:00:00.96 bitrate=8331.0kbits/s speed=0.946x    
    frame=   45 fps= 29 q=24.8 size=    1411kB time=00:00:01.50 bitrate=7706.4kbits/s speed=0.969x    
    frame=   61 fps= 29 q=24.8 size=    1840kB time=00:00:02.03 bitrate=7412.7kbits/s speed=0.98x    
    frame=   76 fps= 29 q=24.8 size=    2241kB time=00:00:02.53 bitrate=7247.8kbits/s speed=0.982x    
    frame=   91 fps= 29 q=24.8 size=    2642kB time=00:00:03.03 bitrate=7136.0kbits/s speed=0.979x    
    frame=  102 fps= 28 q=24.8 size=    2936kB time=00:00:03.40 bitrate=7074.4kbits/s speed=0.944x    
    frame=  116 fps= 28 q=24.8 size=    3310kB time=00:00:03.86 bitrate=7012.5kbits/s speed=0.937x    
    frame=  129 fps= 28 q=24.8 size=    3657kB time=00:00:04.30 bitrate=6966.9kbits/s speed=0.927x    
    frame=  142 fps= 28 q=24.8 size=    4004kB time=00:00:04.73 bitrate=6929.1kbits/s speed=0.918x    
    frame=  155 fps= 27 q=24.8 size=    4350kB time=00:00:05.16 bitrate=6897.7kbits/s speed=0.911x    
    frame=  168 fps= 27 q=24.8 size=    4697kB time=00:00:05.60 bitrate=6871.2kbits/s speed=0.904x
   #At some point it shows the output and then this happens:
frame=  321 fps= 27 q=24.8 size=   10102kB time=00:00:10.70 bitrate=7733.9kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=0.899x    
frame=  335 fps= 27 q=24.8 size=   10530kB time=00:00:11.16 bitrate=7725.1kbits/s dup=4 drop=0 speed= 0.9x    
frame=  349 fps= 27 q=24.8 size=   10959kB time=00:00:11.63 bitrate=7717.0kbits/s dup=6 drop=0 speed=0.899x    
frame=  364 fps= 27 q=24.8 size=   11418kB time=00:00:12.13 bitrate=7708.9kbits/s dup=9 drop=0 speed=0.901x    
frame=  379 fps= 27 q=24.8 size=   11877kB time=00:00:12.63 bitrate=7701.7kbits/s dup=12 drop=0 speed=0.903x    
frame=  394 fps= 27 q=24.8 size=   12337kB time=00:00:13.13 bitrate=7695.5kbits/s dup=16 drop=0 speed=0.905x    
frame=  410 fps= 27 q=24.8 size=   12828kB time=00:00:13.66 bitrate=7689.2kbits/s dup=20 drop=0 speed=0.907x    
frame=  426 fps= 27 q=24.8 size=   13319kB time=00:00:14.20 bitrate=7683.7kbits/s dup=24 drop=0 speed=0.91x    
frame=  442 fps= 27 q=24.8 size=   13809kB time=00:00:14.73 bitrate=7678.1kbits/s dup=29 drop=0 speed=0.912x    
frame=  458 fps= 27 q=24.8 size=   14299kB time=00:00:15.26 bitrate=7672.9kbits/s dup=33 drop=0 speed=0.913x    
frame=  474 fps= 28 q=24.8 size=   14791kB time=00:00:15.80 bitrate=7668.9kbits/s dup=38 drop=0 speed=0.917x    
frame=  489 fps= 28 q=24.8 size=   15253kB time=00:00:16.30 bitrate=7665.6kbits/s dup=42 drop=0 speed=0.918x    
frame=  505 fps= 28 q=24.8 size=   15745kB time=00:00:16.83 bitrate=7662.4kbits/s dup=47 drop=0 speed=0.92x    
frame=  521 fps= 28 q=24.8 size=   16238kB time=00:00:17.36 bitrate=7659.5kbits/s dup=52 drop=0 speed=0.923x    
frame=  535 fps= 28 q=24.8 size=   16668kB time=00:00:17.83 bitrate=7656.9kbits/s dup=56 drop=0 speed=0.923x 

#many duplicated frames
```

Theres no real output picture and idk why. Can someone please help me?

Heres the output picture:
[image]

ffplay command output:

```
  

    libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
      libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
      libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
      libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
      libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
      libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
      libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
      libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
      libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
    [video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x93100630] Raw       :     yuyv422 :           YUYV 4:2:2 : 640x480 160x90 160x120 176x144 320x180 320x240 352x288 432x240 640x360 800x448 800x600 864x480 960x720 1024x576 1280x720 1600x896 1920x1080 2560x1472
    [video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x93100630] Compressed:       mjpeg :          Motion-JPEG : 640x480 160x90 160x120 176x144 320x180 320x240 352x288 432x240 640x360 800x448 800x600 864x480 960x720 1024x576 1280x720 1600x896 1920x1080
    /dev/video0: Immediate exit requestedB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

Comment: I *think* your initial `image2pipe` is incorrect and also that the parameters specifying your input stream must come **before** your `-i`. So I *think* your command needs to start more like this `ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format mjpeg -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0...`

Comment: ... and after that, you probably need to set `-pix_fmt bgr24 -f image2pipe -`

Comment: I did all of that and the output picture is a failure.

Comment: Can I suggest you create two variables called `width` and `height` at the top of your program and use them throughout so that you don't have bare numbers in your `-video_size`, and your `read(640*480*3)` and your `reshape()`. You can use `-video_size`,`f'{width}x{height}'` Then you will rule out errors from mismatching sizes.

Comment: Yeah sry i changed that variables too ofc. But still it shows this picture

Comment: dump a few megabytes of the stream into a file, then use a hex editor to investigate. the patterns in the output indicate that you either receive a lot less than one full bitmap frame, or a lot more -- your sizes **do not match**. in the ffmpeg call, you have 1280x720, and in the python side you have 640x480. you ought to fix that. you can [edit] your question.

Comment: Did you check the available formats? `ffplay -f video4linux2 -list_formats all /dev/video0`

Comment: mjpeg is available in 1280x720

Comment: Can you click [edit] and add in the output from the `ffplay` command so everyone can see it please?

Comment: Can you click [edit] and add the output from the `ffplay` command I suggested 4 comments back please?

Comment: Sry. I did it now

Answer (score 0):

I know what the problem is, but can't put my hands on a suitable Raspberry Pi to check my solution so I'll try and explain.

The VideoCore requires the image to be a multiple of 16 pixels wide and a multiple of 32 pixels tall in order to process it efficiently with Neon SIMD instructions. If it is not, it **pads** the image up to the next multiple of those numbers. So your 1280x720 will actually produce 1280x736 pixels.

So, you need to either:

- leave your `ffmpeg` unchanged, but change your `read()` and `reshape()` to match those padded sizes, or
- add a *crop* video filter to your `ffmpeg` command immediately before output but after `-i /dev/video0`, to make it the size that your `read()` is expecting and leave your `read()` and `reshape()` unchanged.

Comment: what is a "crop video filter". Do you mean -video_size widthxheight. First Option still give the same output

Comment: IDK if this is really the issue. At the point where it actual shows the picture the Frames get duplicated. I edited my question and my ffmpeg output

Comment: `ffmpeg ... -i /dev/video0 -filter:v "crop=1280:720:0:0" ...`

Comment: yeah still dont work.