# OpenCV corrupting HQ Rapsicam data above 4000x3040 resoution?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, raspberry-pi, picamera

## The Problem

When I take an image using OpenCV that is larger than 4000 pixels wide, using a high quality picam, the image data appears corrupted (it's offset).

### More Detail

As stated, I cannot get a good image when using OpenCV at over 4000 pixels wide of resolution. I know that the hardware is not the issue as I can get a clean full resolution (4056x3040) image when I use the raspistill command:

`sudo raspistill -o testing.tiff -w 4056 -h 3040`

Here is the clean output from raspistill:

[4056x3040 image - Clean Image produced by raspistill command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuE8o.jpg)

I am able to capture images using OpenCV in either Python:

```
import cv2 as cv

def main():
    cap = cv.VideoCapture("/dev/video2", cv.CAP_V4L2)
    cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 4056)#works fine up to 4000
    cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 3040)

    if not(cap.isOpened()):
        print("could not open video device")
    else:
        print("cap opened")

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if(ret):
        cv.imwrite("./test_im.jpg", frame)
        print("image saved")
    else:
        print("no capture data returned")
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Or I can capture in OpenCV with C++:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::VideoCapture cap("/dev/video2", cv::CAP_V4L2);

    cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 4056);
    cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 3040);


    if(cap.isOpened() == false){
        std::cout << "cap not opened" << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "cap opened" << std::endl;
    }
    cap >> frame;

    if(frame.empty()){
        std::cout << "empy frame";
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "successfully captured image" << std::endl;
        cv::imwrite("test.tiff", frame);
    }
}
```

The Result is the same either way.

Here is the corrupted output from OpenCV:

[4056x3040 image - Corrupted and captured by OpenCV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFoB5.jpg)

To me it seems as if it something was going wrong with the timing of the capture. The format of which I save it to does not make a difference either. I have tried .png, .jpg, and .tiff. The result is always the same. After reboot the results remain the same.

If I reduce the desired capture resolution to only 4000x3040 then I am able to successfully make a capture. Here are the results:

[4000x3040 image - successfully captured by OpenCV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BMdC.jpg)

I am not sure why this is happening. And would really appreciate any help! Let me know if there is any other information that could be useful!

## System

- Raspberry Pi 4B with 4GB RAM.
- High Quality Picam
- Running Ubuntu 20.04
- OpenCV 4.5.5

Comment: None of the images you have uploaded appear to be anywhere near the size you describe, but I notice the dimensions of the "corrupted" image are slightly off from those of the "clean" image.

Comment: Have a read about padding and multiples here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/72210785/2836621

Comment: Change this "/dev/video2" to "/dev/video0" or "/dev/video1". Otherwise, you change slightly. 4000 to less than 4010. One thing  is are you using 4k monitor? If yes. will do.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Very Helpful!

@KarlKnechtel - The images are different sizes because SO will only let me upload images 2MB or less. The actual captures are the sizes that I stated above. The images that I captured that were the originals were over that limit. In order to have some sort of a visual I resorted to (unfortunately) taking a screenshot of the images in an image viewer. This reduced the size, although I'm sure there are better ways to do this.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have not, I'll check it out and update later if it solves the problem! Thanks!

Comment: @toyotaSupra the video port needs to be "/dev/video2" simply because I am running a different camera on "/dev/video0." I am confident that the "video2" port is the correct port. 

That being said, I do not have a 4K display, but as far as I understand I should be able to view a 4056 image on a lower resolution monitor, but it will just display to me at a lower resolution. My monitor is 3440x1440 and I have not had issues displaying other higher resolution images previously.

Comment: If dealing with large images, you might also consider changing `/boot/config.txt` to increase GPU memory, something like  `gpu_mem=256` and rebooting...

Comment: @MarkSetchell - The link you provided seems to be a similar issue. I have experimented some more with different image sizes. In the other post you mentioned that ffmpeg wants images that are increments of 16 wide. I changed the image width to 4016 and the capture is still corrupted. If I change it to 4032, however, the capture looks great! I tried 4048, and it did not work again. Any insight on how to fix this using opencv? I don't know how to crop or adjust the image during the .read() call because once it has returned it is already resized to be 4056x3040.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I had already adjusted the gpu_mem to be larger previous to this post, before adjusting it I couldn't get this large of captures without the pi crashing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to hear we are getting somewhere at least! Maybe try assuming the width and height must both be multiples of 32 and see if that works. I'm not sure what you mean by changing the width in the `read()`, you should be able to simply use *"Numpy slicing"* to get the part you want, i.e. `smaller = larger[0:3040, 0:4056, :]` to get a 3040x4056 sub-image from a larger (padded) image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ok, I can definitely see the issue now, and it is definitely the padding. I don't know how to get rid of the padding after the fact though. The image streaks move from left to right because there are 8 extra pixels per row that shouldn't be there. And I could potentially leave the image width at 4032, but we'd like 4056 for full res if at all possible. What I meant by change the width in the `read()` is that what OpenCV returns to me is a 4056x3040 image, if I could make it return a 4064x3040 image then all would be solved, as I could chop off the columns containing the padding.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Is it possible that OpenCV is bumping some of the data out of the array since the padding pixels take up some of the space? I can't reshape to a 4064x3040 because there aren't enough pixels.

Comment: I'm not certain a) what you request, b) what you get, c) what you want. Maybe you can supply the 3 things?

Comment: If you get an image with black padding, you should be able to trim that with *"Numpy slicing"* to get rid of the padding. Then you can use `cv2.resize()` if necessary to size up or down.

Comment: I apologize, still learning how best to communicate on SO.

Comment: What I request from OpenCV - a 4056x3040 image that contains the image from the picam. What I get a 4056x3040 image, but with the padding of a 4064x3040 image baked into it and strewn throughout the 4056x3040 image, which is what causes the streaking. What I want - Either a 4056x3040 image that has no padding, or a 4064x3040 image that has the padding, so that I can easily chop it off. Is there a way that I can upload another image somewhere so that I can better illustrate what I mean? Or should I add it to the original question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I determined that the issue was related to a necessary buffer required by the Raspberry Pi and OpenCV. I believe it is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72210785/10432022) answer on stack overflow.

As a result, I was able to fix the image streaking by reducing the resolution that I was requesting to be a multiple of 32 in both length and width e.g. 4032x3040 (instead of 4056x3040). This allowed me to get almost full resolution images, and was sufficient for the task. I was unable to figure out how I would be able to get a full resolution image using OpenCV and a High Quality Raspicam.